# Flutter build iOS Failed - Xcode build error - iOS simulator working perfectly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

flutter build iOS command failed with the following error in the terminal.

**VS code terminal error :**

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/jq/pyr57m6d7gq31fk7j95x9ymh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.ZNQigo/flutter_ios_build_temp_diriiAZpq/t
emporary_xcresult_bundle

```
1 warning generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler_apple-9.0.7/ios/
Classes/strategies/PhonePermissionStrategy.m:50:35: warning: 'subscriberCellularProvider' is deprecated:
first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                  serviceSubscriberCellularProviders
In module 'CoreTelephony' imported from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler_apple-9.0.7/ios/
Classes/strategies/PhonePermissionStrategy.m:8:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:112:50:
note: property 'subscriberCellularProvider' is declared deprecated here
@property(readonly, retain, nullable) CTCarrier *subscriberCellularProvider
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("serviceSubscriberCellularProviders", ios(4.0, 12.0))
API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
                                                 ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:112:50:
note: 'subscriberCellularProvider' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
1 warning generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:41:22: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
      "displayName": displayName,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:41:22: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
      "displayName": displayName,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                 ?? <#default value#>
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:41:22: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
      "displayName": displayName,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                !
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:41:22: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
      "displayName": displayName,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                 as Any
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:42:18: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
      "network": network?.rawValue,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:42:27: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
      "network": network?.rawValue,
                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
                                   ?? <#default value#>
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:42:27: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
      "network": network?.rawValue,
                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
                                  !
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:42:27: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
      "network": network?.rawValue,
                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
                                   as Any
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:68:21: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
      "namePrefix": namePrefix,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:68:21: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
      "namePrefix": namePrefix,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
                               ?? <#default value#>
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:68:21: note: force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
      "namePrefix": namePrefix,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
                              !
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:68:21: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
      "namePrefix": namePrefix,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
                               as Any
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:69:20: warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'
      "givenName": givenName,
                   ^~~~~~~~~
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:69:20: note: provide a default value to avoid this warning
      "givenName": givenName,
                   ^~~~~~~~~
                             ?? <#default value#>
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-
                                                                      !
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pay_ios-1.0.7/ios/Classes/PaymentEx
tensions.swift:74:57: note: explicitly cast to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning
      "phoneticRepresentation": phoneticRepresentation?.toDictionary(),
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                       as Any
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/Location
Plugin.m:176:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is
deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
            ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView'
has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UIAlertView : UIView
           ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/Location
Plugin.m:176:48: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is
deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                               ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView'
has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UIAlertView : UIView
           ^
2 warnings generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/libPhoneNumber-iOS/libPhoneNumber/NBPhoneNumberUtil.m:3482
:51: warning: 'subscriberCellularProvider' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  NSString *isoCode = [[self.telephonyNetworkInfo subscriberCellularProvider] isoCountryCode];
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                  serviceSubscriberCellularProviders
In module 'CoreTelephony' imported from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/libPhoneNumber-iOS/libPhoneNumber/NBPhoneNumberUtil.m:20:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:112:50:
note: property 'subscriberCellularProvider' is declared deprecated here
@property(readonly, retain, nullable) CTCarrier *subscriberCellularProvider
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("serviceSubscriberCellularProviders", ios(4.0, 12.0))
API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
                                                 ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:112:50:
note: 'subscriberCellularProvider' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
1 warning generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+RoundedCorner.m:60:1: warning: category is implementing a method which will also be
implemented by its primary class [-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation]
- (void)addRoundedRectToPath:(CGRect)rect context:(CGContextRef)context ovalWidth:(CGFloat)ovalWidth
ovalHeight:(CGFloat)ovalHeight {
^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+RoundedCorner.m:11:1: note: method 'addRoundedRectToPath:context:ovalWidth:ovalHeight:'
declared here
- (void)addRoundedRectToPath:(CGRect)rect context:(CGContextRef)context ovalWidth:(CGFloat)ovalWidth
ovalHeight:(CGFloat)ovalHeight;
^
1 warning generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Resize.m:96:99: warning: enum values with underlying type 'NSInteger' should not be used as
format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead [-Wformat]
            [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Unsupported content mode: %d",
            contentMode];
                                                                                             ~~
                                                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                             %ld  (long)
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Resize.m:155:13: warning: enumeration values 'UIImageOrientationUp' and
'UIImageOrientationUpMirrored' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
            ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Resize.m:155:13: note: add missing switch cases
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
            ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Resize.m:175:13: warning: 4 enumeration values not handled in switch:
'UIImageOrientationUp', 'UIImageOrientationDown', 'UIImageOrientationLeft'... [-Wswitch]
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
            ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Resize.m:175:13: note: add missing switch cases
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
            ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Resize.m:110:1: warning: category is implementing a method which will also be implemented
by its primary class [-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation]
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize
^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Resize.m:12:1: note: method 'resizedImage:transform:drawTransposed:interpolationQuality:'
declared here
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize
^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Resize.m:152:1: warning: category is implementing a method which will also be implemented
by its primary class [-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation]
- (CGAffineTransform)transformForOrientation:(CGSize)newSize {
^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Resize.m:16:1: note: method 'transformForOrientation:' declared here
- (CGAffineTransform)transformForOrientation:(CGSize)newSize;
^
5 warnings generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Alpha.m:97:1: warning: category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by
its primary class [-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation]
- (CGImageRef)newBorderMask:(NSUInteger)borderSize size:(CGSize)size {
^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/UIImage+Alpha.m:10:1: note: method 'newBorderMask:size:' declared here
- (CGImageRef)newBorderMask:(NSUInteger)borderSize size:(CGSize)size;
^
1 warning generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1/ios/Cl
asses/FlutterNativeImagePlugin.m:77:19: warning: unused variable 'fileName' [-Wunused-variable]
        NSString *fileName = [[fileArgument lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
                  ^
1 warning generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-12.0.3/
ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:6:17: warning: method definition for 'setRegisterPlugins:'
not found [-Wincomplete-implementation]
@implementation FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin {
                ^
In file included from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-12.0.3/
ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:1:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-12.0.3/
ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.h:5:1: note: method 'setRegisterPlugins:' declared here
+ (void)setRegisterPlugins:(FlutterPluginRegistrantCallback *)callback;
^
1 warning generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBr
owser.m:148:42: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appStoreURL];
                                         ^~~~~~~
                                         openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:'
has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBr
owser.m:156:61: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  BOOL openedInBrowser = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                            ^~~~~~~
                                                            openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:'
has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
2 warnings generated.
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:53:3:
warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  SFAuthenticationSession *_authenticationVC;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12:
note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
           ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:143:7
: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC =
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12:
note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
           ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:144:3
7: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          [[SFAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:requestURL
                                    ^~~~~
                                    ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12:
note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
           ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:180:5
8: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                         ^~~~~~~
                                                         openURL:options:completionHandler:
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:'
has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:",
ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:203:3
: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC = _authenticationVC;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ASWebAuthenticationSession
In module 'SafariServices' imported from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12:
note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
           ^
5 warnings generated.
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Environment/NetworkInfo/GU
LNetworkInfo.m:44:37: warning: 'subscriberCellularProvider' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  CTCarrier *provider = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider;
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    serviceSubscriberCellularProviders
In module 'CoreTelephony' imported from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Environment/NetworkInfo/GU
LNetworkInfo.m:23:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:112:50:
note: 'subscriberCellularProvider' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@property(readonly, retain, nullable) CTCarrier *subscriberCellularProvider
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("serviceSubscriberCellularProviders", ios(4.0, 12.0))
API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
                                                 ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Environment/NetworkInfo/GU
LNetworkInfo.m:53:37: warning: 'subscriberCellularProvider' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  CTCarrier *provider = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider;
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    serviceSubscriberCellularProviders
In module 'CoreTelephony' imported from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Environment/NetworkInfo/GU
LNetworkInfo.m:23:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:112:50:
note: 'subscriberCellularProvider' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@property(readonly, retain, nullable) CTCarrier *subscriberCellularProvider
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("serviceSubscriberCellularProviders", ios(4.0, 12.0))
API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
                                                 ^
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Environment/NetworkInfo/GU
LNetworkInfo.m:123:22: warning: 'currentRadioAccessTechnology' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS
12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  return networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology
In module 'CoreTelephony' imported from
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Environment/NetworkInfo/GU
LNetworkInfo.m:23:
/Volumes/NewDisk/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPh
oneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:154:61:
note: 'currentRadioAccessTechnology' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain, nullable) NSString* currentRadioAccessTechnology
API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology", ios(7.0, 12.0))
API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
                                                            ^
3 warnings generated.
remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swif
t:39:52: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained protocol is deprecated; use
'AnyObject' instead
internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDataSource: class {
                                                   ^~~~~
                                                   AnyObject
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swif
t:55:50: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained protocol is deprecated; use
'AnyObject' instead
internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDelegate: class {
                                                 ^~~~~
                                                 AnyObject
/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swif
t:107:14: warning: 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use UIScrollView's
contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
             ^
ld:
'/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBSDKLoginKit/
FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
(Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this
target. file
'/Volumes/NewDisk/Projects/zeydecember/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBSDKLoginKit/
FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/jq/pyr57m6d7gq31fk7j95x9ymh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.ZNQigo/flutter_ios_build_temp_diriiAZpq/t
    emporary_xcresult_bundle
```

**Xcode error output :**

[image: xcode error]

Flutter run command and iOS simulator is working **without any problem.**

Answer (score 0):

1- flutter clean
2- flutter pub get
3- cd to iOS folder
4- pod install
5- ready for build or archive

Comment: Already done and same issue when building